# getting address field from assembly

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

Assume the following solidity code:

```js
function caller(uint k, uint v) public {
    (bool success, ) = address(this).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("callee()", abi.encode(k, v, msg.sender)));
    require(success);
}

function callee() public returns(address sender) {
   // WAY 1
   assembly { sender := calldataload(sub(calldatasize(), 32)) }

   // WAY 2
   assembly { sender := shr(96, calldataload(sub(calldatasize(), 20))) }
}
```

I want to get sender address in "callee" using assembly. Both seem to work for my case, but everyone uses WAY 2 as the best practice. Is there scenarios where WAY 1 wouldn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

## Context

Neither "Way 1" nor "Way 2" are generalized ways to get the sender address of "callee". If you want to get the sender address, you can use the [`CALLER` (`0x33`) opcode](https://www.evm.codes/#33?fork=shanghai):

```
function callee() public returns(address sender) {
   assembly { sender := caller() }
}
```

The assembly in your example appears to originate from the reference implementation in [ERC-2771](https://ercs.ethereum.org/ERCS/erc-2771). ERC-2771 proposes a way for an intermediate "Trusted Forwarder" contract to forward a "Transaction Signer" address to a "Recipient" smart contract, because otherwise the "Transaction Signer" address would be lost after calling the "Trusted Forwarder" contract.

Importantly, **ERC-2771 specifies that the "Transaction Signer" is appended as the last 20 bytes of the calldata.** It does not specify that the calldata is re-encoded:

> The **Trusted Forwarder** is responsible for calling the **Recipient** contract and MUST append the address of the **Transaction Signer** (20 bytes of data) to the end of the call data.

## Short answer

With this context in mind, the brief answer is:

**"Way 1" will only work with `abi.encode`, while "Way 2" will work with `abi.encode` or `abi.encodePacked`.**

## Long answer

As mentioned in the context, the purpose of this assembly is to retrieve the address from calldata, **assuming the address is the last 20 bytes of the calldata**. ERC-2771 does not make any assumptions about how the calldata is encoded, only that the address is the last 20 bytes.

However, "Way 1" assumes that the address is ABI encoded, and that the address must take the last 32 bytes of the calldata. In contrast, "Way 2" gets the the last 20 bytes of calldata and then pads it to 32 bytes.

Here's an example of where "Way 1" doesn't work, from [ERC-2771](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2771#extracting-the-transaction-signer-address):

```
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) = to.call.value(value)(abi.encodePacked(data, from));
```

In this example, "Way 1" will return 12 bytes from the end of `data` along with the `from` address, while "Way 2" will only return the `from` address, padded to 32 bytes.

---

OpenZeppelin's implementation of ERC-2771 updated the inline assembly to plain Solidity [in release v4.9](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/dc44c9f1a4c3b10af99492eed84f83ed244203f6/contracts/metatx/ERC2771Context.sol#L32) (May 2023):

```
return address(bytes20(msg.data[calldataLength - contextSuffixLength:]));
```

So it might not be accurate to say "Way 2" is a "best practice" either.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer. can you put this in "add" ` (bool success, ) = address(this).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("callee()", abi.encodePacked(k, v, msg.sender)));`, you will note that address(in the emitted event) is wrong :) and yes, I am using Way 2

Comment: @ardislu "Way 1 will return 12 bytes from the end of data along with the from address, while "Way 2" will only return the from address, padded to 32 bytes". The OP still casting it to address, which will take most right 20 bytes anyways even in WAY 1